# SQL with subqueries returns multiple error messages

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggeling with some SQL error messages, as far as i can tell it's quite similar to the example i've found on: [dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

> An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 34)*
>
> Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 34)*
>
> A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "SELECT" at position 35)*
>
> Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 240)*
>
> Unrecognized keyword. (near "AS" at position 255)*
>
> Unexpected token. (near "A" at position 258)*
>
> A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "SET" at position 269)*

Here is the code i've used:

```
    UPDATE bank,
    (SELECT * FROM account
        WHERE MIN(id) IN
            (SELECT * FROM account
            WHERE A.used = "0" AND A.amount= bank.amount))
        AS A
    SET bank.attachment = A.attachment, bank.color = "1", A.used = "1", A.color = "1"
    WHERE bank.color = "0" AND A.used = "0"
```

Comment: `MIN(id)` isn't allowed there, so use `WHERE id IN` instead.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this query?

Comment: These subqueries with usage of * are risky. You should provide sample input and expected outcome to show what you want to do.

Comment: You cannot update subquery columns. You cannot refer to subquery column in sub-subquery. You cannot perform implicit GROUP BY with `SELECT *`.